# how to ignore headers while executing a file in unix.

Tags: shell, scripting

I am tying to execute a .CTL file, the file was executed without error wherein the header data got inserted in Table. I have not used $sed command, so do you think is it because of that?
I am not able to back track my script

Comment: I want to ignore it not Delete it .

Comment: Can you show us the .ctl file or tell us that it contains `OPTIONS(SKIP 1)`